# How to configure NodaTime serialization for System.Text.Json in Blazor WASM .Net 6

Tags: serialization, system.text.json, nodatime

How to configure NodaTime serialization for System.Text.Json in Blazor WASM .Net 6? In a WebApi you would do
`builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(settings => settings.JsonSerializerOptions.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb));`

but there are no controllers in Blazor WASM.

This does not work either:
`builder.Services.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(options => options.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb));`

`var options = new JsonSerializerOptions().ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);`
and providing to `HttpClient` does not work either.

Comment: This feels like it's probably not really specific to Noda Time - I'd expect any tutorial/issue that explains how to perform configuration for System.Text.Json in a Blazor WASM project to then apply to Noda Time.

Comment: From my many hours working on this, no such configuration exists. Additionally, using `var options = new JsonSerializerOptions().ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);` and providing those options on every single `HttpClient` request does not work either. It actually causes the entire object to not deserialize correctly and no exception is thrown.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well and trying to isolate it

Answer (score 4):

This works.

`JsonSerializerOptions default = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web).ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);`

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack and a workaround, but I ended up using Newtonsoft for this

```c#
//Should work but doesn't
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions().ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
var customClassList = await Http1.GetFromJsonAsync<List<customClass>>($"api/CustomClass", options);

//First: Get the raw json string        
var response = await Http1.GetAsync($"api/CustomClass");
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

//Second: Deserialize with Newtonsoft
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
var customClassList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CustomClass>>(content, settings);

//Doesn't work (System.Text.Json)
var customClassList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<CustomClass>>(content, options);
```

I suspect this has something to do with Blazor/WASM since the above code is basically the default example for json and nodatime with System.Text.Json. However, I don't get any weird errors or exceptions with in my Blazor app. It just doesn't deserialize properly.